# Reminders.app deleting all reminders after syncing with Exchange

Tags: icloud, big-sur, reminders, exchange

I wanted to share some reminders with a friend who only has Windows.  So I setup my Reminders.app on BigSur to sync to both iCloud and Exchange (Microsoft To Do).

I copy and pasted all my reminders across from iCloud to Exchange in Reminders.app and it was all working great until I deleted all of my iCloud reminders.  Immediately after I deleted the last iCloud reminder list, Reminders.app went nuts and deleted all my reminders in both iCloud and Exchange.

So now I've lost 10 years worth of reminders.

I have TimeMachine backups and I can restore `~/Library/Reminders`. After a reboot if I open Reminders.app I see all of my old reminders, however over the next few seconds Reminders deletes everything again.

I've tries restoring versions of `~/Library/Reminders` which predate my change to sync to Exchange. Reminders.app still deletes everything after the restore/reboot cycle.

I've tried restoring and rebooting with:

- Reminders enabled in `System Preferences - Internet Accounts - iCloud`
- Reminders disabled in `System Preferences - Internet Accounts - iCloud`
- WiFi enabled
- WiFi disabled

and Reminders.app immediately deletes all my reminders in all of the combinations. I'd really like to get my reminders back but am a bit stumped on what else to try!

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Tried turning off Reminders in the Exchange account before the restore cycle?  After that have you tried removing the Exchange account before the restore cycle?

Comment: Yeah, tried both those things.

Never figured out a proper solution, but in the end I did a restore and then `sudo chown -R root ~/Library/Reminders`.  That stopped Reminders.app from deleting everything so at least I could copy and paste all my reminders somewhere else.

Wish I knew why restoring the data didn't fix it!